# What features/menus/fx can I use to make a 3D Character OR Actor Emit Smoke while walking?

Tags: particles

I am trying to achieve the effect shown here: https://youtu.be/RbP5frdcfzQ
I am new to blender, but am specifically looking to do Ghostly FX. I'm looking for a tutorial that shows - Step by step - how to make the entire Body/mesh/skin of a 3D model emit smoke or fog or dust...possibly other particles like magic.

My studio OWNS a MOCAP system, and we currently do 3D animation. I am a producer here, not a 3D artist, though I am familiar with linking emitters, and the overall concept. If anyone has done something like my youtube example, please let me know if 1.YOU have a tutorial you made or 2. One you know of you can send me the link to. Thank you for reading this. Jon Hyers, Producer